# Removing unwanted classes from CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to edit a html template to create a simple version for my need. I delete some ; but is there a tool to remove unused classes from CSS or I need to remove the manually?

For example, `<div class="something">` is not used in my html; but still I have `.something {}` in my css file and make my css heavy. Currently, I delete unused classes from CSS one by one manually. I wonder if there is a way to delete any class in CSS which is not referenced in html!

Comment: Some tools exist that do a pretty good job, but the fact is, with dynamic usage of CSS classes via jQuery (et al), this problem is actually not totally solvable.

Comment: Can you name some or give me a hint. I know the problem you are referring to; but I think it is easier to separate jquery functions and corresponding classes.

Comment: JetBrain's products do a good job, *WebStorm*, *ReSharper*, etc.  I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out something like http://unused-css.com/. If you pay for it, you get to have it crawl your site and create a clean version for the entire site.

If you want a browser-based solution, try the Firefox plugin `CSS Usage`. You can open up Firebug, click on the CSS Usage tab, click on "Autoscan", then navigate your website a few times (be sure to hit every page). It will keep track of which classes are used and you can export a "cleaned" version. This requires more manual work and may be subject to broken styles, but if you are careful, it should work fine.

Comment: Sounds amazing! This is exactly the idea I am looking for. Hope to find similar options too.

Comment: I ran this a while ago and it doesn't completely strip my CSS of unused styles, but it decreased the size by 32% without breaking anything.

Comment: As I see in the change log, lots of things have been improved (I think, let's try it).

Comment: Let us know how it worked! And feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not really, due to the fact a CSS file can be used across a magnitude of HTML pages.

I'm sure some people might have made a tool that parses all their own specific HTML pages and creates a list of 'unused' css classes, but it'd be likely to be very bespoke to their needs (also if the HTML pages render out different things due to a user's choices, how'd you know that the CSS class is or isn't used?)